# can anyone explain this statement on linear dependency

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

When i was reading i encountered the statement"In a linearly dependent set of functions none of the function is zero function".but I cannot understand why the statement is true

Comment: Was that 'linearly independent'?

Answer (score 1):

If the functions are $0,x,x^2$, then $1\times0+0\times x+0\times x^2=0$, and this is not the trivial solution where all the coefficients are zero.  So $\{0,x,x^2\}$ is a linearly dependent set.

Answer (score 0):

if one of the functions was the zero function, say $f$, then $\{f\}$ already would not be linearly independent, as $cf(x)=0$ for all $c$ in the ambient space and $x$ in your domain.